# My photo in google search result

Tags: seo

Sometimes we see a small thumbnail with google search result as in the following screen shot. I want to display my picture when my website url is displayed in the search result. T
[image]

Comment: This has something to do with Google plus account. The images are from Google plus..., not sure how you can put one, but do check that..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google has stopped the author photos being shown on Google. And the update of Google authorship has no longer been processed and Google said they will not recover the authorship update.

Answer (score 1):

This is Google's implementation of [Authorship Markup](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2011/06/authorship-markup-and-web-search.html), using HTML5's `rel="author"` and XFN's `rel="me"` markup on web-pages to attribute articles to the original author.

They have more implementation information on their [Webmaster Help](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=1408986) section.

[UPDATE] Today they [announced you can set-up authorship by using your email address](http://insidesearch.blogspot.com/2011/10/set-up-authorship-using-just-your-email.html).